# Show/Hide div on click, but stop when already showing

Tags: jquery, html

The two tabs on top of the sidebar on my clients side shows/hides divs and text depending on which one has been clicked. But if you click an already open tab the text for the second div will appear when it shouldn't.

If 'Parts' is clicked when already open, the text for brand center will appear too.
If 'Brand Centre' is clicked when already open, the text will be removed.

Trying to prevent this from happening, some way of knowing it's already opened etc.

Live site: http://bit.ly/TcHxkS
Left sidebar on homepage.

HTML

```
<div class="category-sidebar">
    <p id="parts-info">FAI Auto stock over 125,000 parts, to find out more select a parts category from below.</p>
    <p id="brand-intro">Welcome to the FAI Brand Centre. This part of our web site allows our agents and customers to be able to download photographic &amp; graphical material in a variety of formats so that marketing material can be reproduced with a consistent FAI look and feel.</p>
    <div id="category-list">
        <?php
            $args = array(
                'menu'       => 'sidebar-menu',
                'container'  => 'true',
            );
            wp_nav_menu( $args );
        ?>
    </div>
```

jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#parts-tab").click(function(){
      $("#brand-login").hide();
      $("#category-list").show();
      $('#brand-tab').removeClass('sidebartabs-active-black');
      $('#parts-tab').addClass('sidebartabs-active');
    });
    $("#brand-tab").click(function(){
      $("#category-list").hide();
      $("#brand-login").show();
      $('#brand-tab').addClass('sidebartabs-active-black');
      $('#parts-tab').removeClass('sidebartabs-active');
    });
    $("#brand-tab").click(function(){
      $("#catalogue-btn2").hide();
      $(".category-sidebar").addClass('black');
      $(".inner-category-sidebar").addClass('black');
      $("#brand-login").addClass('black');
    });
    $("#parts-tab").click(function(){
      $("#catalogue-btn2").show();
      $(".category-sidebar").removeClass('black');
      $(".inner-category-sidebar").removeClass('black');
      $("#brand-login").removeClass('black');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: try to add condition if ($(*your_selector*).is(":hidden"))

Answer (score 0):

This part in your code is making a problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#brand-intro").hide();
        $("#brand-tab").on("click", function(){
            $("#brand-intro").toggle();
            $("#parts-info").hide();
        });
        $("#parts-tab").on("click", function(){
            $("#brand-intro").toggle();
            $("#parts-info").show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

You should put a condition when to show/hide "#brand-intro". Actually, if I understood you correctly, this part of code should look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#brand-intro").hide();
        $("#brand-tab").on("click", function(){
            $("#brand-intro").show();
            $("#parts-info").hide();
        });
        $("#parts-tab").on("click", function(){
            $("#brand-intro").hide();
            $("#parts-info").show();
        });
    });
</script>
```